# Form validation and arrays, How to contract multiple if and else statements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I was working on validating the registration form in JavaScript. I decided to add red color text style to identify wrong inputs.
I have two arrays: `fail[]` that contains messages for each failed input and `lblcol[]` that has different label id's.

```
 var fail = new Array();

 fail[0] = validateNickname(form.form_nickname.value);
 fail[1] = validatePassword(form.form_password.value);
 fail[2] = validateFirstname(form.form_firstname.value);
 fail[3] = validateLastname(form.form_lastname.value);
 fail[4] = validateEmail(form.form_email.value);

var lblcol = document.querySelectorAll("#lbl0, #lbl1, #lbl2, #lbl3, #lbl4");

if (fail[0]!="")
lblcol[0].style.color="red";
else 
lblcol[0].style.color="black";
if (fail[1]!="")
lblcol[1].style.color="red";
else 
lblcol[1].style.color="black";
if (fail[2]!="")
lblcol[2].style.color="red";
else
lblcol[2].style.color="black";  
if (fail[3]!="")
lblcol[3].style.color="red";
else
lblcol[3].style.color="black";
if (fail[4]!="")
lblcol[4].style.color="red";
else 
lblcol[4].style.color="black";
```

Is there a faster way to add this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a simple loop. The loop would iterate through each of the values in the array, and then perform this test. I've also changed the `if-else` statement to a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) statement. Here is what the code would look like:

```
for (var i=0;i<fail.length;i++) {
    lblcol[i].style.color = fail[i]!="" ? "red" : "black";
}
```

What this loop would do is first set the variable `i` to `0` (via the code `var i=0;`), then test if `i<fail.length`, which will be true for the first 5 iterations, since `fail.length` is 5. After then executing the contents of the forloop, it increments by 1 (via the code `i++`), and starts over from the part where it tests `i<fail.length`.

Within the loop, it assigns a colour to the `lblcol` of index `i`, and assigns the value `"red"` when the value at index `i` in the array `fail` is not equal to an empty string, and otherwise it assigns the value `"black"`.

Comment: @ItlikeBooom if this was the answer you were looking for, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark just to the left of my answer's content. It'll make clear that this answer has been answered, and it'll also show that this answer solved the problem for you, in case anybody ends up on this page looking for the same answers.